# Confidence interval for binomial data in R?

Tags: r, statistics, probability, confidence-interval

I know that I need mean and s.d to find the interval, however, what if the question is:

> For a survey of 1,000 randomly chosen workers, 520 of them are female. Create a 95% confidence interval for the proportion of workers who are female based on the survey.

How do I find mean and s.d for that?

Comment: Perhaps look at the answers posted here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17802320/r-proportion-confidence-interval-factor

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You can also use `prop.test` from package `stats`, or `binom.test`

```
prop.test(x, n, conf.level=0.95, correct = FALSE)

        1-sample proportions test without continuity correction

data:  x out of n, null probability 0.5
X-squared = 1.6, df = 1, p-value = 0.2059
alternative hypothesis: true p is not equal to 0.5
95 percent confidence interval:
 0.4890177 0.5508292
sample estimates:
   p 
0.52
```

You may find interesting the article [TWO-SIDED CONFIDENCE INTERVALS FOR THE SINGLE PROPORTION: COMPARISON OF SEVEN METHODS](http://stats.org.uk/statistical-inference/Newcombe1998.pdf), where in Table 1 on page 861 are given different confidence intervals, for a single proportion, calculated using seven methods (for selected combinations of n and r). Using `prop.test` you can get the results found in rows 3 and 4 of the table, while `binom.test` returns what you see in row 5.

Comment: Nice answer, and it doesn't require any external packages.

Comment: @thelatemail This is probably a dumb question, but how do you take that 95% CI and turn it into a SE and then an SD?

Comment: prop.test gives very strange results. If you compare it with SAS. I would prefer to use binconf from Hmisc package (see @Zbynek answer) with known method for CI calculation.

Comment: The link is broken

Comment: @Julien I think I found it. I've updated the link.

Answer (score 23):

In this case, you have binomial distribution, so you will be calculating [binomial proportion confidence interval](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_proportion_confidence_interval).

In R, you can use `binconf()` from package `Hmisc`

```
> binconf(x=520, n=1000)
 PointEst     Lower     Upper
     0.52 0.4890177 0.5508292
```

Or you can calculate it yourself:

```
> p <- 520/1000
> p + c(-qnorm(0.975),qnorm(0.975))*sqrt((1/1000)*p*(1-p))
[1] 0.4890345 0.5509655
```

Comment: What would q-norm be is you use 99% confidence interval?

Comment: `qnorm(0.99)` is 2.326348

Answer (score 23):

Alternatively, use function `propCI` from the [`prevalence`](https://CRAN.R-project.org/package=prevalence) package, to get the five most commonly used binomial confidence intervals:

```
> library(prevalence)
> propCI(x = 520, n = 1000)
    x    n    p        method level     lower     upper
1 520 1000 0.52 agresti.coull  0.95 0.4890176 0.5508293
2 520 1000 0.52         exact  0.95 0.4885149 0.5513671
3 520 1000 0.52      jeffreys  0.95 0.4890147 0.5508698
4 520 1000 0.52          wald  0.95 0.4890351 0.5509649
5 520 1000 0.52        wilson  0.95 0.4890177 0.5508292
```

Answer (score 6):

Another package: [`tolerance`](https://CRAN.R-project.org/package=tolerance)  will calculate confidence / tolerance ranges for a ton of typical distribution functions.

Comment: wow, that package `tolerance` is comprehensive & thorough. outstanding recommendation!