# How to get confidence interval?

Tags: r, confidence-interval

It is given that 37 people have a positive result of the disease test and 69 a negative result. What is the 95% confidence interval for the proportion of positive test results?

Comment: This is about R, not RStudio.  Try searching for answers first.  This is a duplicate question of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21719578/confidence-interval-for-binomial-data-in-r

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
binom.test(37, 37+69)

        Exact binomial test

data:  37 and 37 + 69
number of successes = 37, number of trials = 106, p-value = 0.00244
alternative hypothesis: true probability of success is not equal to 0.5
95 percent confidence interval:
 0.2590333 0.4477520
sample estimates:
probability of success 
             0.3490566
```